# PHP Image Optimization

Tags: php

I need some ways to dynamically optimize images using PHP. Sample codes or a module would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: ps: no one knows what you mean by "dynamically optimize images". optimize...how? for file size? for image clarity? what do you mean by "dynamically"?

Answer (score 4):

you can use thimthumb.php

go to your .htaccess

than add

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*\.(png|jpg))$ /timthumb.php?q=100&src=$1
</IfModule>
```

"q=100" is for the quality you can set it betwen 0-100
than creat a new file "img.php" in the home directory eg: www.your-website.com/timthumb.php

http://timthumb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/timthumb.php

than find this

```
// Get original width and height
        $width = imagesx ($image);
        $height = imagesy ($image);
        $origin_x = 0;
        $origin_y = 0;

        // generate new w/h if not provided
        if ($new_width && !$new_height) {
            $new_height = floor ($height * ($new_width / $width));
        } else if ($new_height && !$new_width) {
            $new_width = floor ($width * ($new_height / $height));
        }
```

and replace it with this

```
 // Get original width and height
    $width = imagesx ($image);
    $height = imagesy ($image);
    $origin_x = 0;
    $origin_y = 0;

  // don't allow new width or height to be greater than the original      
    if( $new_width > $width ) {     
        $new_width = $width;        
    }       
    if( $new_height > $height ) {       
        $new_height = $height;      
    }   

    // generate new w/h if not provided
    if ($new_width && !$new_height) {
        $new_height = floor ($height * ($new_width / $width));
    } else if ($new_height && !$new_width) {
        $new_width = floor ($width * ($new_height / $height));
    }
```

so when you go to www.your-website.com/images/pict.png it's like your loading 
www.your-website.com/img.php?q=100&src=/images/pict.png
hope you like this! & sorry if i couldn't explaing well because my english is not good. :D

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by optimize? If you wish to keep the dimensions but reduce the size, take a look at [imageJpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) for an example, and specifically the third argument (`quality`). Consider `100` to be perfect quality, and start decreasing it to find an optimal balance between quality and size.

Answer (score 0):

very simple one is here too:
just change quality value (60) from 1 to 100, as you wish.

after execution of script, look at the filesize, and thats way, define your optimal quality value.

[source](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/php_image_optimization)